# IP address conflict according to Linksys

Tags: networking, router, ip, cable-modem

Apparently my Arris SB8200 Modem is causing an ip address conflict with my Linksys AC2200 Velop Mesh Router. The web gui address for the SB8200 is 192.168.100.1 and Velop is 192.168.1.1. According to Linksys since they are in the same class they are conflicting with each other and forcing the Velop to Switch to a 10.xx.xx.xx address. It will do this randomly or when i power cycle the velop router. I have never heard of a modem causing an ip conflict when the ip address is in the same class and is only used to access the web gui.

Comment: Because it sounds like you are using the Linksys for all your routing and networking, you should actually look in to placing your SB8200 in to “bridge” mode. This turns off the routing on the cable modem and passes through the public IP address so that the Linksys does all the work. If you have trouble figuring it out you can call Comcast and they can help. Reboot your Linksys and fix the network address if necessary after putting the modem in bridge mode. Otherwise, apart from that just change the modem to a different network address to prevent the conflict (10.x.x.x).

Comment: The sb8200 is just a modem there is no router or WiFi on it at all

Comment: Yes. That looks correct. However, according to [this thread](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r31442754-SB8200-Comcast-Bridge-Mode) the modem does not go in to bridge mode until after it has established a connection with your ISP. Prior to that it will give out IP addresses in the 192.168.100.x range. Can you confirm your Linksys is configured with the address 192.168.1.1 AND a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 or /24, whatever one it shows? The addresses don’t conflict, but if it’s going to keep complaining you might need to change it permanently to 10.x.x.x.

Comment: Basically this problem occurs when both units reboot and the Linksys comes online before the cable modem.

Comment: If I could upvote comments than you would have a +1 for the subnetmask question.

@OP: 192.168.100.1 and 192.168.1.1 are not network classes. As stated those are just IP addresses, and depending on the network mask they can be in the same network or in completely independant networks. With both on 255.255.0.0 (/16) they could be in the sane network. With an expected /24 (255.255.255.0) they are not.

Answer (score -1):

I have the solution for all Velop users that cannot acces their Arris Surfboard modem. 
I cannot promise this will work on all models, but it works on my Surfboard SB8200.
Load up the Linksys Smart WIFI on your PC. Go to Security. Turn off firewall protection. 
Now you can go to http://192.168.100.1. It will take about 30 seconds to load.

If you feel uncomfortable with the firewalls off, you can simply turn them back on when finished viewing what you need to see,
Hopefully this works with all Arris Surfboard modems.

Frankly I'm surprised the tech support team did not know or post this easy fix. It would have saved a lot of user frustration.

Tech support is supposed to help, not fight, end users. I know because I have been a PC and networking tech for decades.